# While Writing into Excel file getting Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, apache-poi

While Trying to write into Excel file getting `Null pointer Exception` coming from line `sheet.createRow(1).createCell(5).setCellValue("Pass");`
Not getting why this error is coming :(

```
package com.qtpselenium.Test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.qtpselenium.util.Xls_Reader;

public class ReturnTestCaseResult {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path =System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\com\\qtpselenium\\xls\\suiteA.xlsx";
        /*   Xls_Reader xlsr = new Xls_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\com\\qtpselenium\\xls\\suiteA.xlsx");
           ReportDataSetResult(xlsr, "TestCaseA1", 3, "Pass" , path);*/
        
         ReportDataSetResult("TestCaseA1", path);
    }

    
    public static void ReportDataSetResult( String TestCaseName , String path){
        
        
        System.out.println(TestCaseName +"----"+ path);
          try {
            FileInputStream fileinp = new FileInputStream(path);
              XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
              
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(TestCaseName);
             
              sheet.createRow(1).createCell(5).setCellValue("Pass");

              FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(path);
              workbook.write(fileout);
              fileout.close();
              
              
              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
          
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the no arg constructor to create the workbook:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

which means there are no sheets in the workbook. This means your sheet variable will be null. I think you want to pass the FileInputStream fileinp into the workbook constructor so that it reads from an existing file?

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileinp);
```

Otherwise you will need to create a sheet called TestCaseName in the workbook before you can start adding rows to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, row(1) is null, you can try to create it first.